# Leaf-Similar Trees

Tags: tree, depth-first-search

Question's URL: https://leetcode.com/problems/leaf-similar-trees/

### Question:

> Consider all the leaves of a binary tree, from left to right order,
> the values of those leaves form a **leaf value sequence**.
>
> [image]
>
> For example, in the given tree above, the *leaf value* sequence is `(6, 7, 4, 9, 8)`.
>
> Two binary trees are considered leaf-similar if their leaf value
> sequence is the same.
>
> Return `true` if and only if the two given trees with head nodes `root1`
> and `root2` are leaf-similar.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> [image]
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> root1 = [3,5,1,6,2,9,8,null,null,7,4], 
> root2 = [3,5,1,6,7,4,2,null,null,null,null,null,null,9,8]
> ```
>
> Output: true
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> root1 = [1], 
> root2 = [1]
> ```
>
> Output: true
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> root1 = [1], 
> root2 = [2]
> ```
>
> Output: false
>
> #### Example 4:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> root1 = [1,2], 
> root2 = [2,2]
> ```
>
> Output: true

### My code:

```
class Solution:
    def leafSimilar(self, root1: TreeNode, root2: TreeNode) -> bool:
        def dfs(node1, res=[]):
            if res == None:
                res=[]
            if node1:
                self.leafSimilar(node1.left, None)                
                self.leafSimilar(node1.right, None)
                if node1.left == None and node1.right == None:
                    res.append(node1.val)
                return (res)  
        return (dfs(root1)) == (dfs(root2))
```

20 cases passed but it was stuck on 21st test case.
The test case where it failed:

```
Input: root1 = [1,2,3], root2 = [1,3,2]
Expected Output: false
```

My output = True

Turns out leaf nodes are [2,3] and [3,2] and thus it says true when it shall not. I have tried using list and set as I thought that will compare the sequence but no luck. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `leafSimilar` recursively, but `dfs`. Also, there is no need to pass `dfs` a second argument, as the idea is to let one call return a list that has the leaves in the given node's subtree. So it is independent from other calls. Then concatenate the lists you get from the left and right child together into one list:

```py
def dfs(node1):
    if not node1:
        return []
    res = dfs(node1.left) + dfs(node1.right)
    if node1.left is None and node1.right is None:
        res.append(node1.val)
    return res
```

The initial calls of this function can stay like you had it, although the extra parentheses are not really needed:

```py
return dfs(root1) == dfs(root2)
```

Little NB: when comparing with `None` the common practice is to use `is` (identity) instead of `==`.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back?